# Question about cross product of 2 vectors, need help!

Tags: vectors, cross-product

If the cross product of $2$ vectors is the surface they clamp. if you let one vector go against zero, shouldn't be cross product then be the lenght of the other one?
I'm hoping for explanation.
I mean if you let one vector go against an infinite small amount towards zero, the cross product should be the lenght of the other vector.

Comment: It might help if you use clearer language. A cross-product is a vector, not a surface. "Surface" also could mean a lot of different things; the vectors determine a parallelogram, but they also determine an entire plane (provided they are not parallel and neither one is zero). And I don't know what you intend by the word "clamp" in this context, but it might be clearer if we knew exactly what kind of "surface" you mean.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not, note indeed that more in general

$$|S|=|A\times B|$$

but

$$|A\times 0|=0$$

[image]

(credit Wikipedia)

Comment: so in all other cases, the crossproduct would result in the surface they clamp?

Comment: The modulus of the corss product is always equal to the area they clamp. But if one vector is very small the area also is very small.

Comment: ok i visualiced it correctly, iam an idiot haha

Comment: @LaffaYett That's good clarify any doubt! Bye

Answer (score 1):

No: when you shrink one vector to zero, the parallelogram becomes infinitely thin, and thus its area goes to zero as well.